# What is the probability that somebody will arrive at least 5 minutes after the other?

Tags: probability

> Alice and Barbara arrange a meeting at a specific place. They arrive at the place at random times between 4pm to 5pm. The girl who arrive first is going to wait 15 minutes and then leave the place if the other girl doesn't arrive.
>
> What is the probability that the girls meet each other?
>
> What is the probability that they arrive exactly at the same moment?
>
> What is the probability that Alice will arrive at least 5 minutes after Barbara?

The answer to the first question is $ 1-(\frac{3}{4})^2$

The answer to the second question is $ 0(zero) $

What would be the answer to the 3rd question and why?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is easiest to attack this kind of problem using a probability-space diagram.

Let $x$ be the time at which Alice arrives - uniformly distributed over the interval 0 to 60 minutes.

Let $y$ be the time at which Barbara arrives - uniformly distributed over the interval 0 to 60 minutes.

If Alice arrives at least 5 minutes after Barbara, then $x \ge y+5$ or $y \le x-5$.

It is possible to see that this gives a triangle with area that is $0.42$ of the whole square.

Comment: plz, provide a picture.